# Deployment and upload key for Google Play - how to use them with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-console

I have created a Cordova hybrid app and somehow managed to sign them for Google Play, starting the process with two commands:

```
1. keytool ...
2. cordova run android --release keystore==... password=...
```

After uploading the signed app on the google console and opting for their upload key, I got access to two certificate files: *deployment_cert.der* and *upload_cert.der*, and their "hash-codes". This makes me pretty confused. What should I do with them? How can I use them to sign the app for Google Play? (I only use JavaScript for the project, and Cordova commands. Do I need Java or something?)

What makes me even more perplexed is the fact that I was able to ignore those certificates and launch the app on Google Play using just the original keystore (by repeating the command 2 above). 
So did I sign the app with the upload key? I don't believe so. And how could I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you enrolled your app in the Google Play App Signing program, you let Google create and own the private key that will be used to sign the APKs that get delivered to the end users (i.e. the *deployment key*).

**The private key that you used to sign the APKs you first uploaded to the Play Console is what Play calls the *upload key***. This is the key that you will need to use to sign all future APKs you upload to the Play Console. What the Play Console does is that it looks at the first APK you upload, extract its certificate, and will verify for every future uploads that the APK uploaded matches the same certificate.

The certificates being displayed in the *App signing* page are just there for informative purposes. The *upload certificate* is the certificate associated with the private key you used to sign your APK, and the *deployment certificate* is the certificate associated with the private key that Play Console created and uses to re-sign the APKs. You only need these hashes if your app uses a third-party API that requires authentication to register your app with that third-party service.

I hope that clarifies it a bit.

The official documentation can be found here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Answer (score 1):

So there are basically three signing certs you need to track.  The first is the debug cert which is usually installed via the android studio.

https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

The second key is the release key you make. Basically you are specifying a keystore file you made using keytool.  This is the one you use to sign your app for production.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore nfty.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk  [your app name]

/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk [your app name].apk
```

BUT WAIT, there's more.

The playstore will RESIGN your app again with it's own key, which you can have it keep for every update.  This is the ONLY key you need once your app is published for the release app to authenticate, it's also the one you would base64 for facebook login.  This is what the .der file contains, the sha1 for your key. To get the base64 you would use:

```
cat [app name]_cert.der | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```